# How do use createSpyObj to mock an Observable in an Angular constructor?

Tags: angular, rxjs, jasmine, observable

So I'm trying to solve this puzzle and I've been searching for answers and I'm a bit stuck.

I'm working on a team, and I've been task with fixing some broken Jasmine Unit tests.

One of our components which is basically for presentation mostly has a construction that gets a service injected into it. Pretty common for Angular.

The component is set up like so

**AppComponent**

```
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private myDataService: MyDataService,
  ) {

    this.myDataService.myDataObservable.subscribe((data: MyData) => {
      if ( data ) {
        this.updateProduct( headerData.productAlias );
      }
    });
  }
```

So what I've been trying to do is the most basic of tests, to just make sure it compiles.

**AppComponent.Spec**

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {

  let myDataService: MyDataService;

  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let el: DebugElement;

  let DataServiceSpecMock: any;

  beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {

    const DataServiceSpecMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('MyDataService',['myDataObservable'])

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        {
          provider: MyDataService,
          useValue: DataServiceSpecMock
        }
      ]
      })
      .compileComponents();

        myDataService = TestBed.inject(MyDataService);
       
        // TRYING TO RESOLVE THIS AS IF IT IS IN THE CONSTRUCTOR
        myDataService.myDataObservable.subscribe.and
         .returnValue(of(true))

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        el = fixture.debugElement;
        fixture.detectChanges();

 
  }));

  it('should create the app', () => {

    // FAILS
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

No matter what I try I can't get it to mock the subscribe function and compile the test. I usually just get the same error.

```
"Failed: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined"
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've looked at lots of examples, but most of them are not in constructors. My guess is this is some sort of asynchronous issue.

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You almost had it.

```
 // TRYING TO RESOLVE THIS AS IF IT IS IN THE CONSTRUCTOR
        myDataService.myDataObservable.and
         .returnValue(of(true));
```

That should do the trick. When you return `of(true)` for the function, this will return an observable and then you can subscribe to it.

** Edit **

To fix the comment you have, remove the `const` from this line:

```
const DataServiceSpecMock = ...
```

You need to use the same `DataServiceSpecMock` that you have declared already with a `let` in the outside scope.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the feedback, but i tried it without the subscribe and now I get different error ` Failed: Cannot read property 'and' of undefined `

Comment: Check out my edit, that should hopefully fix it.